# Как отобразить значение InstallPath из реестра в консоли?

Tags: c#, реестр

[image: Ошибка]

Нужно, чтобы значение `InstallPath` отображалось в консоли.

Что я делаю не так?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RegistryKey hklm = Registry.LocalMachine;
            RegistryKey hksf = hklm.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE");
            RegistryKey hkvl = hksf.OpenSubKey("Valve\\Steam");
            object readypath = hkvl.GetValue("InstallPath");
            readypath.ToString();
            hkvl.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(readypath);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы задать 32-битное представление реестра на 64-битной системе, используйте `RegistryView.Registry32`. Т.е. Ваш код будет выглядеть как-то так

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var lmRegistry = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32))
        {
            var steamRegistry = lmRegistry.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam", false);
            string readypath = steamRegistry.GetValue("InstallPath").ToString();
            Console.WriteLine(readypath);
        }
    }
}
```

Подсмотрено из [Reading the registry and Wow6432Node key - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2039186/reading-the-registry-and-wow6432node-key)

Answer (score 0):

Вы слишком намудрили с кодом. Всё проще:

```
using (var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Valve\Steam"))
    if (key != null)
        Console.WriteLine(key.GetValue("InstallPath"));
```

Comment: Не выводит в консоль значение

Comment: @Павел Посмотрите, равен ли `key == null` в отладчике. А потом посмотрите, скольки битное ваше приложение — от битности зависит ветка реестра.

Comment: key == null, хотя в реестре не так. Извините, если это так элементарно. Может использую не тот метод

Comment: @TheBottle У вас процесс 32-битный или 64-битный?

Comment: 64 битный выбран в vs, если правильно вас понимаю

Comment: @TheBottle Попробуйте выбрать 32 бита. Эта строка хранится в 32-битной ветке.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/RRD3P.png в 32 бит

Comment: @TheBottle Вы неправильно скопировали путь: собачку скопировали, а слэши двойные оставили. Может, из-за этого?

Comment: Попробовал убрать скобки потом собачку, результат такой же

Comment: Тоже первый раз столкнулся с таким поведением.. При x86 Ваш код не работает, при Any Cpu все хорошо... Так вот при x86 данное значение у меня ищется как hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam")

Comment: @elp87 Опана,вот так находит значение,но для 64 бы

Comment: string XZUGHIVUXZGXIUVGUIZXVUI4548979 = (string)Microsoft.Win32.Registry.GetValue(@"HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Valve\Steam", "SteamPath", null); Универсальный

Comment: @TheBottle, не совсем. Это решает конкретно Ваш вопрос, но это связано с тем, что steam прописывает свой путь в 2 разных местах. Кстати, у меня hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\Valve\Steam") работает на всех платформах (х86, х64, Any CPU)